# TypeError: Tabular.Table is not a function

Tags: meteor, datatables, aldeed-tabular, aldeedmeteor-tabular

I'm getting 'TypeError: Tabular.Table is not a function' while working with aldeed:tabular. Here is the detailed error:

```
/Users/nathancain/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2.zi1w5b++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
                        throw(ex);
                        ^

TypeError: Tabular.Table is not a function
    at meteorInstall.contactsTable.js (contactsTable.js:6:26)
    at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:181:9)
    at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:106:16)
    at /Users/nathancain/Dropbox/development/flt/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/app.js:1318:1
    at /Users/nathancain/Dropbox/development/flt/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:295:34
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/nathancain/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2.zi1w5b++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at /Users/nathancain/Dropbox/development/flt/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:128:5
    at /Users/nathancain/Dropbox/development/flt/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:344:5
    at Function.run (/Users/nathancain/Dropbox/development/flt/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:480:12)
Exited with code: 1
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Here is lib/contactsTable.js:

```
import Tabular from "meteor/aldeed:tabular";
TabularTables = {};
TabularTables.Contacts = new Tabular.Table({
    name: "Contacts",
    collection: Contacts,
    columns: [
        {data: "firstName", title: "First"},
        {data: "lastName", title: "Last"},
    ],
    search: {
        caseInsensitive: true,
        smart: true
    }
})
```

What do I need to do to troubleshoot/fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a conflict with yogiben:admin. I removed it and now aldeed:tabular is working.